# can I compute a RIS at a specific time on the chart?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am wondering if it is possible to compute the RIS on a specific point of a chart when I selectively choose that point?
Lets say I choose a specific time and price and I want to compute the rsi with length 14 for that specific point:

```
price1_val = input.price(0, "Price 1", inline="price", confirm=true)
price1_time = input.time(0, "Time", inline="price", confirm=true)
```

Is there a way to compute the RSI for that specific `price1_time` where the close of candle is `price1_val`?